# HAProxy UDP Load Balancing

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, haproxy, syslog, syslog-ng

I'm trying to configure my ubuntu as a load balancer with HAProxy. Since the 2.3 version is also UPD supported. So, basically, I want to configure my Ubuntu as a load balancer with HAProxy in order to send logs (UDP port 514) to 2 of my Syslog-ng server. Following my configuration:

```
frontend Local_Server
bind 10.172.0.6:514
default_backend my_syslog_server

backend my_syslog_server
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server syslog-ng01  10.172.0.3:514 
    server syslog-ng02  10.172.0.4:514
```

How looks my configuration like? is it right like this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try to make you config file like this:

global

log stderr format iso local7

ring myring

```
description "My local buffer"
format rfc5424
maxlen 1200
size 32764
timeout connect 5s
timeout server 10s
# syslog tcp server
server mysyslogsrv 127.0.0.1:514 log-proto octet-count
```

log-forward sylog-loadb

```
dgram-bind 127.0.0.1:1514
bind 127.0.0.1:1514
# all messages on stderr
log global
# all messages on local tcp syslog server
log ring@myring local0
# load balance messages on 4 udp syslog servers
log 127.0.0.1:10001 sample 1:4 local0
log 127.0.0.1:10002 sample 2:4 local0
log 127.0.0.1:10003 sample 3:4 local0
```

Ref Link : https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html